# How can I get a network applet in MATE panel?

Tags: network-manager, indicator, gnome-panel, mate

I have Ubuntu MATE 14.10. Today, I accidentally removed the applet from the panel which lets me choose the WLAN network. How can I get it back?

(The same applet seems to have shown the battery status)

### What I've tried

My `/etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop` looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Network
Comment=Manage your network connections
Icon=nm-device-wireless
Exec=nm-applet
Terminal=false
Type=Application
NoDisplay=true
NotShowIn=KDE;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=NetworkManager
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=nm-applet
X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=nm-applet
```

When I execute

```
$ nm-applet
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon
```

it does not crash, but nothing happens ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that I removed the notification area. This includes the volume indicator, the network applet and the battery status. The solution is simple:

Add the notification area to your panel. You do so by right-clicking on the panel, "Add to Panel..." and choosing **Notification Area**:

[image]

This gives you the network manager applet (nm-applet), the sound / volume chooser and the battery indicator.