# Connecting to vPN in Ubuntu 18

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, 18.04, openvpn

I am actually using MATE, but for all intents and purposes it is Ubuntu 18. At any rate, I am trying to connect to a VPN. The particular VPN I am trying to connect to L2TP+IPsec.

I installed the correct repo:

```
 sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp
```

and I have the option to create the proper VPN connection.  The connection shows up in my Network Connections (see photo)

[image: Network Connections Window]

Whenever I click on the connection, I am directed to edit the information.  How do I physically connect to the VPN? Am I missing a setting here? Do I need to connect via command line?

I have also noticed that since the upgrade to Ubuntu 18, the network connections icon is missing from the task bar. How can I add this back?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have first hand experience on the nm-applet disappearing from MATE panel issue, but it was answered here :

- [Can’t get network applet back in Ubuntu MATE 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031950/can-t-get-network-applet-back-in-ubuntu-mate-18-04)

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS includes network-manager-l2tp in the default repo, there is no PPA repo that needs to be added.

Unless you are using KDE, you also need to install the GNOME based connection editor component with :

```
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp-gnome
```

To avoid Ubuntu bug [LP#1778946](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1778946) which breaks DNS resolution after disconnecting the VPN connection, install the resolvconf package :

```
sudo apt install resolvconf
```

Comment: for me in github there is no 1.3.12 branch anymore, but only 1.3.13, i am trying that

Comment: No longer need to build the xl2tpd source code as a workaround. Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) and 16.04 (xenial) now have xl2tpd packages with the backported patch to workaround this kernel issue in their respective updates repositories.

Comment: @douglas - why don't you edit your answer instead of just providing a comment?  Some readers might mistakenly follow those instructions.

Comment: @sage, thanks, I've trimmed my answer by removing redundant instructions, but have added some other relevant newer instructions.